# Flujo de ejecución dentro del case de una sentencia switch

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

Buenas programadores de C. Estoy realizando un juego de plataforma en C++ para un trabajo que tengo que hacer.
El jugador se maneja con las flechas. En cierto momento el jugador pasa por un objeto (una escalera) por el que puede subir si cuando la posición en el eje x del jugador coincide con la de este objeto y presionas la flecha hacia arriba, el jugador sube.
La gestión de las teclas se hace por medio de un switch y usando la librería GLUT y OpenGL (es obligatorio hacer el programa con esta librería).
Mi problema y con lo que me estoy rompiendo la cabeza es que al cumplirse las condiciones mencionadas, el jugador efectivamente sube, pero no para de subir. La idea es que cuando llega al fin de la escalera, detecta que está en la siguiente plataforma y debe pararse. Os adjunto el código del switch:

```
switch (key) {
case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
    if(player.LimitePlataforma(plataforma1) || player.LimitePlataforma(plataforma2))
        player.setVel(5.0f, 0.0f);
    break;

case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
    if (player.LimitePlataforma(plataforma1) || player.LimitePlataforma(plataforma2))
        player.setVel(-5.0f, 0.0f);
    break;

case GLUT_KEY_UP:
    while (player.Interaccion(escalera1)) {
        if (player.LimitePlataforma(plataforma3)) {
            player.setVel(0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        else
            player.setVel(0.0f, 5.0f);
        break;
    }
    break;
```

El problema está en este último case. Ahora mismo está programado con un bucle while de pruebas que he estado haciendo. También he probado con ifs anidados pero nada.
Osea, entiendo el motivo por que no para, y es que al pulsar la tecla evalua si el jugador está o no en línea con la escalera, si está en línea sube y si no sale del case. En caso de estar en línea, como en un primer momento el jugador no está en la siguiente plataforma, comienza a subir. Pero ahí ya sale del case y no me evalúa la siguiente instrucción para que se pare al detectar que ha llegado.
He pensado en usar la instrucción "continue" pero no sé muy bien cómo funciona la verdad.
¿Sugerencias?
No puedo hacer uso de librerías externas que no sean las típicas (math, string, fstream), ni windows ni nada, todo con glut y gl.
Muchas gracias al que me ayude :)

Comment: No está muy claro cómo el caso de subir es diferente de ir a la izquierda o a la derecha. ¿Para qué necesitas el bucle? Parece que necesitas simplemente eliminarlo.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. la idea es que al cumplirse la condición de que el jugador esté sobre la escalera y pulses la flecha hacia arriba, el jugador suba la escalera y al detectar que ya la ha subido se pare.

Comment: ¿Cómo es esto diferente de ir a la izquierda y parar cuando golpea la pared?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. una vez sube o baja la escalera debe poder moverse. Si hago el mismo planteamiento que para la plataforma pero en el eje y, al subir la escalera se quedaría permanentemente parado

Comment: Si el botón es GLUT_KEY_LEFT y puedes moverte a la izquierda, entonces empieza a moverte a la izquierda.  Si el botón es GLUT_KEY_UP y puedes moverte hacia arriba, entonces empieza a moverte hacia arriba. En cualquier caso, deja de moverte cuando no puedas seguir moviéndote en esa dirección. No veo ninguna diferencia entre los dos casos.